# Permissions error when saving file (sandbox)

Tags: macos, cocoa, save, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to save a file to a path, in a sandboxed application [OS X], but so far am getting an error almost every time I try to save. The error is..

```
Error saving: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “test.txt” in the folder “Testing”." UserInfo=0x1001f5e70 {NSFilePath=/Users/Seb/Desktop/Testing/test.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x1001f5d70 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

I have set "User Selected File" of my entitlements to "Read/Write Access".

My code..

```
NSString *saveLoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt",[[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"saveURL"]] path],self.theWindow.title];
NSURL *saveURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveLoc];

NSLog(@"Saving to: %@",saveLoc);

NSError *err = nil;
[self.textView.string writeToURL:saveURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

if (err) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving: %@",err);
    [[NSAlert alertWithError:err] beginSheetModalForWindow:self.theWindow
                                                       modalDelegate:nil
                                                      didEndSelector:NULL
                                                         contextInfo:nil];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I save the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to the read/write a file outside the sandbox, you must get user access to that file or one of the directory above. The access can be gained by using `NSOpenPanel`, `NSSavePanel` or drag and drop.

The access to those files/directories is lost after the app terminates.

In order to get permanent access to a file/directory selected by the user, you must use [Security-Scoped Bookmarks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16).

Comment: Looks like I'm going to need a security-scoped bookmark then, for permanent access. Thanks!

Comment: After a bit of pain figuring it out, and the help of http://objcolumnist.com/2012/05/21/security-scoped-file-url-bookmarks/ I got it working perfectly.

Comment: I've wrapped the process of requesting permission and persisting that permission up in this class, use it if you like. https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess