# Sandbox mac osx application

Tags: macos, sandbox

I have developed a mac application without using sandbox.
now i want to send it to the mac appSore, i buy my certificate, all is good.
I read this: [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4) and in xcode i set the `user selected file`,`music folder`... to `read/write access`.
My application let the user chose from a folder any type of file, do some treatment and let the user chose where to save the new file. 
To chose files, user can open folder with `NSOpenPanel` or with the `open with` functionality or drag-and-drop files.

Also the application can delete files.

I dont know if there's other things to do to sandbox the application (or a tool to test if it is sandboxed)
I come from ios this is why i'm asking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in the Console when the application is running to view if sandboxd or pboxd logs messages referring to your application.

The format is: `sandboxd[53037] ([53035]): AppName(53035)`

I don't know if there are other processes who may log sandbox violation, but you can see them, if they are referring to your application.

Comment: No sandboxd log :) i'll wait for other replay before accept yours :) thank you.

Comment: now i have a problem in destination folder, if i set it 'programmatically' i have a permission denied error, but if i use an NSOpenPanel its ok.
can i set ones the destination folder (default folder) without redefine it in all time i want write a file ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139587/permissions-error-when-saving-file-sandbox/13141353#13141353