# Objective c cannot write file to directory permission issue

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I need to save some image on directory which is created by the app, here is the code to create the directory and set full permission

```
NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
SnapDir = [AssetPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ScreenCaptures"];
if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:AssetWatchSnapDir isDirectory:&isDirectory] || !isDirectory)
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    [manager createDirectoryAtPath:SnapDir
                 withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                 attributes:nil
                 error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error creating directory snap path: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    else {
        NSError *error1;
        [manager setAttributes:@{ NSFilePosixPermissions : @0777 }
                     ofItemAtPath:SnapDir error:&error1];
    }
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:SnapDir forKey:@"AssetSnap"];
```

Now I have saving the image png like,

```
SnapDir = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AssetSnap"];  
NSString* filepath = [SnapDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSError *error;
bool success = [pngRep writeToFile:filepath options:0 error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"writeToFile failed with error %@", error);
}
```

This works fine when if the image save happen at the same instance of app run of  directory creation. That is I open application, created directory by the application and then save.

Where as when close the application and open it again and try to save the image(using the destination path stored at `NSUserDefaults`), it gives the following error regarding permission issue.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “2016_08_19_06_32_00.png” in the folder “ScreenCaptures”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/development/Documents/d/ScreenCaptures/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 [manager createDirectoryAtPath:SnapDir.path
                  withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                   attributes:nil
                                        error:&error];
```

or

```
 [manager createDirectoryAtPath:SnapDir.relativePath
                  withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                   attributes:nil
                                        error:&error];
```

**I didn't test this code**

Comment: Actually SnapDir is of `NSString`  type, I couldn't find `path` or `relativePath` for it.

Comment: Can you paste the value of SnapDir?

Comment: Yes it's there in the error message `/Users/development/Documents/d/ScreenCaptures/`

Comment: I think the problem is related to the thread described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139587/permissions-error-when-saving-file-sandbox